# How to split a string based off elements in a list

Tags: python, string, list

```
statuses = ['421-A','421-G','ARTICLE 11','ARTICLES 14 & 15',
            'COOP/CONDO PLAN FILE','EVICT COOP/CONDO', 'GARDEN COMPLEX'
            'J-51','NON-EVICT COOP/CONDO','ROOMING HOUSE','SEC 608']

snip = [('11201', '131', 'MULTIPLE DWELLING A', '421-A ARTICLE 11', '291', '45')]
```

Each line of my file looks like `snip`. I have a list of statuses, some of which contain whitespace.

I want to check statuses and if I see them in `snip[0][3]`, split the string accordingly. It's possible for `snip[0][3]` to be an empty string `('')` but it will have no more than three statuses listed here.

So where it currently says: `'421-A ARTICLE 11'`. I want this to appear as `'421-A'`, `'ARTICLE 11'`. This will expand the length of `snip` and that's OK.

I have tried `map`, `zip`, `lambda`, and list comprehensions using `any()`. I feel like I'm close and that there is an elegant solution for this problem but cannot find it. I was trying to avoid regex, but if that is needed it's fine.

UPDATE:

Current code that seems to be very close to working now that I changed 'snip' to lists instead of tuples.

```
snip = ['11201', '131', 'MULTIPLE DWELLING A', '421-A ARTICLE 11', '291', '45']
status_break = [s for s in statuses if s in snip[3]]
newline = snip[:3] + status_break + snip[4:]
print(newline)
```

Comment: What rule are you using to split the string in `snip[3]`? or is it just if one of the strings from `statuses` appears in it?

Comment: @quamrana either none of the strings from status will be there and split[3] will be an empty string, or up to three items from statuses will be there, all mashed into one string as seen in snip.  '421-A ARTICLE 11' is actually two statuses.

Comment: Could you post your existing attemps? They may be a good base to review.

Comment: There is no `snip[3]`. `snip` is a list with 1 element in it. That element is a tuple with 6 elements. Did you mean `snip[0][3]`? Why do you have the tuple nested in a list?

Comment: Good catch. I updated post to snip[0][3]. I went ahead and changed my code so I can work with lists instead of tuples. Should be easier to handle now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[s for s in statuses if s in snip[0][3]]
```

with regex:

```
import re
statuses = ['421-A','421-G','ARTICLE 11','ARTICLES 14 & 15',
            'COOP/CONDO PLAN FILE','EVICT COOP/CONDO', 'GARDEN COMPLEX'
            'J-51','NON-EVICT COOP/CONDO','ROOMING HOUSE','SEC 608']

snip = ' '.join(statuses)
statuses_re =  map(lambda s : (s,re.compile('(^| )%s($| )' % s)),statuses)
print([s[0] for s in statuses_re if s[1].search(snip)])
```

but if you have statuses like 'GARDEN COMPLEX', 'GARDEN COMPLEX 1', 'GARDEN COMPLEX 2' it isn't work

Comment: This seems good for step one. Now I would need to take the elements of this list ["412-A","ARTICLE 11"] and insert or replace the previous element "412-A ARTICLE 11". Thoughts on the cleanest approach?

Comment: I think the most simple way is that:
snip[0][3] = [s for s in statuses if s in snip[0][3]]

Comment: I would note that I am getting unexpected behavior here. My status list has both "NON-EVICT COOP/CONDO" and "EVICT COOP/CONDO". This solution is returning both items as matches when it should only return a match for "NON-EVICT COOP/CONDO". I believe I'll need to use regex to handle this. Or is there anyway to modify the list comprehension to handle only exact matches?

Comment: this is more complex, but I will try something here